# Should instancetype be used on alloc/new/init methods?

Tags: objective-c, clang, instancetype

According to the [clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#objective-c-features), a method that returns `id` is implicitly known to return `instancetype` when it is a class method beginning with `new` or `alloc`, or an instance method beginning with `retain`, `autorelease`, `init`, or `self`.

For the sake of consistency, should these methods also be written to explicitly return `instancetype` in new code?

```
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // perform initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Is there any documentation on why or why not, or any reasoning? It seems that in this case it's interpreted exactly the same to the compiler.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It isn't actually necessary because the compiler automatically promotes such methods to returning `instancetype`, effectively (as you stated).

This [automatic inference](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html) is documented in the llvm documentation.

Personally? I always declare them as `instancetype` explicitly because it exactly describes the contract and it makes for easier refactoring later.

Comment: The default is "id", not instancetype. Returning instancetype gives you more type checking. There's no difference if your code is correct, but the compiler might miss mistakes if you return id.

Comment: @gnasher729 See the instancetype documentation in llvm (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html).  `instancetype` is automatically inferred for certain methods and, as a result, `instancetype` is the default in those cases.